# Setup for Login with Facebook and my own OAuth. Usage of Facebook tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I need to setup communication between my iOS/Android app and my PHP backend. I want to use facebook account only for logging in, there is no further communication with facebook. I have User accounts in my system and facebook_id is only a parameter to identify user.
Is it ok to verify the user by checking the token on the graph api from my backend just at the beginning and then only use my own tokens for communication or do I need to recheck if the user is still logged in on facebook from time to time (which is actually irrelewant for me as there are no fb interactions).
What else is there to consider?
Do I need a separate token for my server? Or do I use my App Secret

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use your application token.

The only scenario it might not work in is if the user deletes your app and decides to login again. From what I've read the app scoped IDs may change in this scenario.

Comment: yes, but it's ok - the app should be enabled. I think this would be the case in any scenario with fb oauth

Comment: @jeff No this is only a case with Facebook specific API v2.0 and above. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: does it mean if user disables the app and than reenables the id remains the same or not?

Comment: In cases I have tested, the id remains the same, but I've heard from other developers where the ID changes.

Comment: ok, I hope not but will keep this in mind. But what does it mean for account mappings - should I use email instead of fb_id to identify user or a combination of both?

Comment: I'd prob steer towards a combination of both